# GNU Icecat source code. Where to find a specific line?

Tags: firefox, browser, themes, gnu, source-code

I've been using GNU Icecat Browser (libre Firefox version made by Gnuzilla) for some weeks. I've been diving through its menus and I found an error:

When I get into the 'Customize Mode' (the one that lets you organize your toolbars and stuff), I find a little drop-down menu saying 'Themes', and an option called 'Get More Themes' inside it.

If I click it, it will redirect me [here](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/icecat/themes), which will return an error. I want to modify the line of code of that redirection, in order to fix that URL, but I can't find it with `grep -Rli /icecat/addons/ /usr/share/`. Maybe am I searching in the wrong folder? Maybe the command is wrong?...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Taking a look at the source code (for Icecat 9.0.1), the URL you give does not appear to be present anywhere in the code explicitly. In fact, the string "icecat/addons/" does not appear anywhere in the source code.

Given the fact that the incorrect URL does not include this string, though, it doesn't make much sense to be search for it. Instead, it would make more sense to search for "/icecat/themes/".

To answer the question of where the incorrect URL may be in the source code, the file ./browser/app/firefox.js includes the line `pref("extensions.getMoreThemesURL", "http://www.gnu.org/software/gnuzilla/addons.html#themes");`(on line 203). This is the correct URL for the themes page, right? If you are working with an older version of the source code, I would expect that the problem lies in that file. The file ./testing/mozmill/tests/shared-modules also contains the line `{name: "extensions.getMoreThemesURL", old: "addons.mozilla.org", new: "preview.addons.mozilla.org"}`, so that may also be of interest.

Comment: Awesome! I found another solution a while ago: the 'defective' URL seems to be in a place I couldn't find, but assuming Firefox and Icecat share some folders, I started looking for /browser/app/icecat.js, which didn't exist. Instead, I found a .js file in which you can add custom preferences to Icecat, so I added a firefox theme pref Iine and saved the document. Worked like a charm, I'll keep tweaking it tomorrow. By the way, I want to publish the solution I reached in the official Gnuzilla mailing list. Do you want to be given credit for having helped me?

Comment: @xvlaze It sounds like you mostly managed to get the solution yourself, so I don't think you need to credit me.